# mount point available in desktop Removable Media using shell command line

Tags: command-line, mount, kde, systemd-mount

How mount a mount point available in desktop/file manager under `Removable Media` category but has not ever been clicked so not been recognized from shell yet, by use of command line?
Then only if this first click was done, it further can be recognized and used on shell by commands

Comment: For full clarity: what file manager are you using? E.g. I see "Removable Devices" in the left panel of Dolphin (KDE's default file manager). Are we referring to the same list of devices? Also, which KDE version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a systemd system you likely have [`udisksctl`](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/udisksctl.1.html), from the `udisks2` package. Quoting the [`udisks(8)` manual](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/udisks.8.html):

> udisks provides interfaces to enumerate and perform operations on disks and storage devices. Any application (including unprivileged ones) can access the udisksd(8) daemon via the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the [system message bus[1]](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/).

Use

```
$ udisksctl status
```

to list the devices you can act upon,

```
$ udisksctl info --block-device /dev/sdXn
```

to inspect them (either the block device `sdX` or one of its partitions, `sdXn`) and

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdXn
```

to mount a volume. The command will output the full path of its mount point. Finally, to unmount and power-off a device:

```
$ udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/sdXn
$ udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdX
```

#### See also

- [How to mount an image file without root permission?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32008/315749)
- [Mounting from dolphin vs commandline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62676/315749)
- [Eject / safely remove vs umount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178638/315749)